# Can't install Libreoffice of OpenOffice

Tags: libreoffice

Two weeks ago I converted my windows machine to Ubuntu.  I made the mistake of deleting LibreOffice to load OpenOffice which I have been using for years.  OpenOffice appears to load correctly but is no where to be found.  When I try to run the f the machine tries to fix LibreOffice and I just run in circles.  I have followed countless forum suggestions for fixing, cleaning, installing, deleting, reinstalling and although I am happy with Ubuntu, I desperately need one office suite or another.  I am desperate!  Any thoughts beyond the first line obvious? Thanks.

Comment: Try :`sudo apt-get --reinstall install libreoffice`

Comment: Could you be more specific about the guide that you followed. The more guides you follow without control the less we know what happened.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to completely remove LIBREOFFICE as **there seems to be a conflict betwen LIBREOFFICE and OPENFFICE**, and then re-install openffice (in fact after reinstalling openoffcie you can safely reinstall libreoffice via a download source ONLY):
1c) To remove LIBREOFFICE, write in a terminal window:

sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice*

sudo apt-get clean

sudo apt-get autoremove

2) To remove OPENOFFICE, do the same:

sudo apt-get remove --purge openoffice*

sudo apt-get clean

sudo apt-get autoremove

3) Then you can safely download the latest OPENOFFICE version for your system (32 or 64bit) and install by going in the downloaded folder in the DEBS subfolder (after having unpacked it) and typing:

cd OOo_inst_folder/DEBS
sudo dpkg -i *.deb

Then go to the desktop integration subfolder.

cd desktop-integration
sudo dpkg -i *.deb

You can find an installation tutorial of OPENOFFICE [HERE](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=74&t=68)